# input iterator skipping whitespace, any way to prevent this skipping

Tags: c++, istream

I am reading from a file into a string until I reach a delimitting character, the dollar symbol.  But the input iterator is skipping whitespace so the string created has no spaces.  not what I want in this case.  Is there any way to stop the skipping behaviour?  and if so how?

Here is my test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

// istream iterator is skipping whitespace.  How do I get all chars?
void readTo(std::istream_iterator<char> iit, 
            std::string& replaced)
{
   while(iit != std::istream_iterator<char>()) {
     char ch = *iit++;
     if(ch != '$')
      replaced.push_back(ch);
     else
        break;
   }
}

int main() {
   std::ifstream strm("test.txt");
   std::string s;
   if(strm.good()) {
       readTo(strm, s);
       std::cout << s << std::endl;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because streams are by default configured to skip whitespace, therefore, use

```
noskipws(strm);
```

---

Standard:

> ### basic_ios constructors
>
> #### `explicit basic_ios(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);`
>
> Effects: Constructs an object of class basic_ios, assigning initial values to its member objects by calling `init(sb).`
>
> #### `basic_ios();`
>
> Effects: Constructs an object of class `basic_ios` (27.5.2.7) leaving its member objects uninitialized.
>   The object shall be initialized by calling its `init` member function. If it is destroyed before it has been
>   initialized the behavior is undefined.
>
> [...]
>
> #### `void init(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);`
>
> Postconditions: The postconditions of this function are indicated in Table 118.
>
> ```
> +----------+-------------+
> | ...      | ...         |
> | flags()  | skipws|dec  | 
> | ...      | ...         |
> +----------+-------------+
>   (Table 118)
> ```